# Array of functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm developing a `vue-based` system, and for my tables, I'm using this: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2

The component has lots of options. There's the possibility to define custom cell templates to manipulate data before showing them, like this one for the "created_at" column:

```
 templates: {
                created_at(h, row) {                   
                  return this.formatDate(row.created_at);
                },    
              //(...)                      
            }
```

I can add other templates as well:

```
var user_id = function(h,row){return row.id};
...

templates: {
                created_at(h, row) {                   
                  return this.formatDate(row.created_at);
                },    
              user_id,                  
              (...) // etc

            }
```

But I'd like to group the functions into a variable, so I could reuse the code, like:

```
 var custom_template = [
        { user_id(h,row){return row.id} },
        { user_name(h,row){return row.name} },
        { created_at(h, row){return this.formatDate(row.created_at)} }                 
    ];

 templates: {                
            custom_templates                                                    
        }
```

EDIT 1:
So i could have something like:

```
templates: {                
          user_id(h,row){return row.id} ,
          user_name(h,row){return row.name} ,
          created_at(h, row){return this.formatDate(row.created_at)}                                                    
        }
```

It's not working, but is it possible? Do I need extra code to achieve this?
Thanks! =)

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to use an array of functions, when the `template` option only accepts objects? Technically you can create a "base" class of templates (an object containing functions), and use `Object.assign(...)` to add additional templates, if required, to the `template` option.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var custom_template = [
  function user_id(h, row) {
    return row.id;
  },
  function user_name(h, row) {
    return row.name;
  },
  function created_at(h, row) {
    return row.created_at;
  }
];

custom_template.forEach(
  item => console.log(item(1, {
    id: 1,
    name: "test",
    created_at: new Date()
  })));
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my functions declaration, but those functions are not called by me, the "custom_template" variable should generate a "array of functions" inside component's instantiation. I edited the question =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine Igor's solution to create array of functions with some form of expanding the array, such as the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)